# How to anti-alias 3D projected contour lines, ArcScene is jaggy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, rendering, arcscene

I'd like to render some high quality contour lines in 3D. The image below was created in ArcScene. Note how ArcScene doesn't use any antialiasing, so the contour edges look jagged and nasty. Click on the image to see it at native resolution, it's only 736 pixels wide.

Does anyone know a solution to create high quality, antialiased GIS vectors in 3D. Can QGIS do it, or should I look into another solution like AutoCad or perhaps another 3D package? Ideally I'd rather stick to a GIS package than a non GIS 3D renderer as I don't have much familiarity with 3D file formats.

If anyone wants to access the 3D shapefile (750kb) it is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=67835268494369557964).

[image]